# how to add a parameter in this i.e if I am asked to add parameter in this sql code , pls guide?

Tags: sql, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_VEN_PROC( ERRBUF VARCHAR2,
ERROUT VARCHAR2,
p_from_period  varchar,
p_to_period    varchar   
)
```

Comment: First you need to decide parameter name, data type and position.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure who is stopping you from doing so -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_VEN_PROC( ERRBUF               VARCHAR2,
                                          ERROUT               VARCHAR2,
                                          p_from_period        VARCHAR,
                                          p_to_period          VARCHAR,
                                          YOUR_NEW_PARAMETER   EXPECTED_DATATYPE
)
```